# German news/text data set

Tags: data-request, language, nlp, europe, media

I am looking for (possible buy) a dataset of German news data (i.e., the largest daily newspapers), where the data span at least ten years back up until now/recent.
Any tips?

Comment: What will it be used for? Are you looking for certain phrases and keywords and how they are used more or less over time? Maybe we can help you with another similar source.

Answer (score 6):

I think a good source would be the **[COSMAS II-Korpora](http://www.ids-mannheim.de/cosmas2/projekt/referenz/korpora.html)** from the [Institut für Deutsche Sprache](http://www.ids-mannheim.de).

It seems there is [free registration](http://www.ids-mannheim.de/cosmas2/projekt/registrierung/) and downloads for non-commercial use.

Answer (score 3):

[**Event registry**](http://eventregistry.org/) provides access to news articles from more than 100.000 news sources in 15 languages including German. The only problem is that you can only get access to the last 3 years of articles.

You can easily get the access to the data using the Python library available here: https://github.com/gregorleban/EventRegistry/

[image]